# How long time will deploying take?

Tags: git, google-app-engine

I am deploying to App Engine from a Git repo at Google Developers Console.
At my local console I add, commit and "git push origin master" to have it all sent to Google. Sometimes it works, sometimes it's slow, sometimes the process breaks half ways for a number of reasons.

This time "Deploying" is still spinning (Google Developers Console, Source Code, Releases) and the Duration is above 1100 seconds at the moment. Is there anyway I can see what's going on, and/or is there a way to cancel the current deploy process and start over?

Doing another "git push origin master" seems to not cancel the first deployment, just add another. It seems undefined what will happen.